# Literal objects and properties reactivity in Vue 2.5

Tags: vuejs2, vue-reactivity

Why nested fields of literal objects bound to a component’s property do not get reactive and observed?

Example:

```
<my-comp :my-prop="{ my: { literal: { object: { with: { nested: { field: ‘not reactive’ }}}}}}"></my-prop>
```

When you do this inside my-comp:

```
created() {
  console.log(this); // you can see in the Chrome console that nested fields of this.myProp do not get reactive (i.e. no getters)
}
```

I know that I can play around it, but I am just asking why not?
Is there a neat way to make it reactive?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is because the way "HTML" templates are rendered.

When Vue "compiles" your html, it basicly creates the following "computed" function

```
render(createElement) { /* `createElement` is also known as `h` in the Vue world */
    return createElement('my-comp', {
        props: {
            myProp: { my: { literal: { object: { with: { nested: { field: ‘not reactive’ }}}}}},
        },
    );
},
```

Since the full flow of the value of `myProp` never passes through the data function, nor through the return result of a *normal* computed function, it never gets marked for reactivity.

While it might sound weird that Vue marks the return result of all "computed" functions, expect the special render function reactive, it actually makes sense if looking at the design idea of Vue, namely props in, and events out. This not marking of reactivity gives us a performance boost here, compared to marking it reactive.

If you still require it to be reactive (and thus want to go against the core principles of Vue (and thus making your application harder to understand) ), you can do it, by storing the value inside the data section of your component, or by returning it from a computed property.